# IntelliJ IDEA: generate html

Tags: intellij-idea

I wonder, if such feature exists:

Generate html-code from sources according to user's fonts/colors settings for further pasting on blogs, forums, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**File | Export to HTML...** or you can install [Copy as HTML](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?idea&id=190) plug-in.

Comment: Use the copy as HTML plugin, it is not limited to colors added by the syntax highlighter. So it can display output from more advanced analysis of the code.